# Body content is overwriting the footer

Tags: html, css

I am using Bootstrap to make a website with a fixed footer. It happens that the body content is overlapping the footer, just like this 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGf8x.png).

By the searchs I made, the footer is less important than the body. I tried putting and ID on the footer but did not solved the problem. Help me please.

```css
footer {
 position:fixed;
  height:35px;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 text-align: right;;
 color: snow;
 background-color: #9e0000;
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

footer h6{
 line-height: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <h6>Universidade Federal de Alagoas</h6>
  <h6>@2017</h6>
</footer>
```

Comment: The likely culprits are either that the body has a higher `z-index`, or has an overflow. Can you paste the code for the body as well please? It looks as though it's generated from a database, so you'll need to post the HTML **output**, not the script to query the database.

Comment: Add this just above your Footer `<div class="clearfix"></div>` . I think `float` is used in your body.

Comment: I am having some trouble to post the full html, js and css, because are thousands of lines and would be really hard to find what you may be looking for. What is the HTML output?

Comment: -Pratyush , did not worked :/

Comment: I upload the folder of the project, if anyone wants to take a look: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4m2n599mt982eq0/Safira.rar?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment so here's some bad assumptions:

You may have something on your table that's `position: relative/absolute` and `z-index: 2+`.
https://codepen.io/chunyin/pen/MmXbJy

to fix this, set your footer to a higher z-index using: 
`z-index: 99;`

edit: I've checked your code, adding this to your css would fix the problem:

**CSS:**

```
footer {
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way you can add a div and give it to height like below code example.

**CSS**

```
.content {
  height:calc(100vh - 35px); 
  /* 35 px THIS IS YOUR FOOTER HEIGHT YOU CAN CHANGE AS YOU WANT*/
}
```

Comment: I tried the z-index: 99; answer first and it solved the problem, but thanks for the effort :)